# populate mongoose key as part of object

Tags: express, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

**EDIT**
[minimal reproduction repo](https://github.com/ASJvine/vod-platform/tree/mongoose-minimal-repro)

It's easier to explain in code than English.
The following code works, but it feels like there's gotta be an easier, more MongoDBy/mongoosy way ...

```
// recipeModel.js, relevant part of the schema
equipments: [{
  _id: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'equipments',
  },
  quantity: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
}],

// recipeController.js
const equipmentsWorkaround = recipe => Object.assign({}, recipe.toObject(), {
  equipments: recipe.toObject().equipments.map(equip => ({
    quantity: equip.quantity,
    name: equip._id.name,
    _id: equip._id._id,
  })),
})

const getItem = (req, res, next) => {
  Recipes.findById(req.params.id)
    .populate('equipments._id')
    .then(equipmentsWorkaround) // <--- ugh ...
    .then(recipe => res.json(recipe))
    .catch(next)
}
```

I know how to do a "conventional" `ref` in mongoose, but is what I'm after here even possible in mongo?

desired outcome:

```
equipments: [
  {
    quantity: 1,
    name: "Pan",
    _id: 'some mongo object here...'
  },
  {
    quantity: 3,
    name: "Big Knife",
    _id: 'some mongo object here...'
  }
]
```

Comment: Are you trying to populate ref of sub document from the same collection ?  What is `.populate('equipments._id')` expected to do ? Can you explain a little bit more here ? Why cant you use embedded doc here ?

Comment: Could you post you expected outcome (in JSON)?

Comment: @DanGreen-Leipciger Added at the end of the question. is that what you meant?

Comment: Could you post what the raw (from mongo, unprocessed by mongoose) `equipments` array looks like

Comment: Right now, it look self-referencing

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are after. You can get the desired outcome by changing your `equipments` to embedded `equipments: [{
  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  name:String,
  quantity: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
}]`. Now mongoose should be able to map it when you fetch the recipes. Populate is not applicable here.

Comment: @Veeram tried it with and without Populating, didn't work

Comment: @Veeramthe I've added the expected result to the question's body. `equipments` is a standalone model, with it's own `CRUD` methods.

Comment: Can you provide a minimally reproducible set up ?

Comment: @Veeram Added to the top of the body, thanks :)

Comment: Can you try with the latest 4.9.6 mongoose version ?